# What is the new location for Flash Builder 4.5 for PHP plugin update?

Tags: php, flash-builder

When I try to update the Flash Builder 4.5 for PHP I receive the following: "No repository found at http://downloads.zend.com/fbphp/updates/4_5"  I understand that zend guys moved the location of the plugin somewhere....  maybe you know what's the new location?  Greatly appreciate for your help in advance.

Comment: Sapir didn't answer my question that is where the link went...  I cannot find the new URL.  Its nothing to do with the installation!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen this? Some discussions gave the following link as a solution:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/895/cpsid_89514.html

What the results?